# Get ACF custom field in media - Twig/Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I created a gallery with ACF custom field "gallery". But I would like to add more settings on each photo.

For that I created two ACF custom fields that I added to the Wordpress Medias to determinate a size and a position for each image. On the screenshot below : "Taille" and "Position" dropdown lists are my custom fields.

In the back office :
"photo_size" is the name of the custom field for the dropdown list "Taille"
"photo_position" is the name of the custom field for the dropdown list "Position"

I manage to create my photo gallery but I don't manage to get those additional custom fields.

I tried this :

```
$file = get_field('show_gallery');
$photo_size = get_field('photo_size', $file['ID']);
$context['photo_gallery'] = $photo_size;
```

I try to get the value of 'photo_size' attached to each image :

```
{% for item in photo_gallery %}
    <img src="{{ Image(item).src }}" class="gallery__img {{ item.photo_size }}" alt="{{ Image(item).alt }}">
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Comment: Try asking on the dedicated wordpress stack exchange too

Comment: You need to put the ACF field variables inside your loop. Otherwise, ACF has no way of knowing what data you're trying to receive

Comment: @DavidBrossard good idea

Comment: @disinfor, how to put those variables ? I'm trying to get "photo_size" field

Comment: In your screenshot, where is `photo_size`? How are your ACF fields setup?

Comment: @disinfor, I updated my post to be more clear. "photo_size" is the name of the custom field I had to the medias. In the screenshot is "Taille" dropdown list. I don't manage to get the value of this dropdown list attached to the media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $photo_size an array? It doesn't look like it. What do you get if you {{ dump(photo_gallery) }}? Or var_dump($photo_size) in your php file? It looks like you should be looping through the show_gallery field not the photo_size field but it is difficult to tell given the field names and that we can't see your field setup (some language barrier here no doubt - if I could speak French I could probably get the idea better). Basically, we need to know how that show_gallery field is set up then I'm sure it will become clearer.

So perhaps you should have something like:

```php
$context['photos'] = get_field('show_gallery');
```

then

```php
{% for item in photos %}
    {% set photo_size = function('get_field','photo_size',item.id) %}
    <img src="{{ item.url }}" class="gallery__img {{ photo_size }}" alt="{{ item.alt }}">
{% endfor %}>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. "show_gallery" is the custom field type "gallery" of ACF. I created others customs fields to add infos on each image. But those customs fields are not displayed in the array of "show_gallery"

Comment: This one: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/? If that's the case, there is no src item in that array, try item.url - is that printing the URL for each image in the gallery?

Comment: And the gallery field is an array so you cant do that $photo_size = get_field('photo_size', $file['ID']); as there is no ID in the $file array. The $file array should be an array of arrays.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english. I updated my post to be more clear. Yeah in fact I'm trying to get the custom fields attached on each image. I made a gallery custom field. I manage to display each image but I don't manage the additional custom field I attached on each image

Comment: Yeah, no problem, I get what you are saying now. I think you need to pass the ID when you get that field so it knows where you want to get the field from (it would be trying to get it from within your array but that field doesn't exist there).

Comment: Do you know how to pass this ID ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately {{ photo_size }} return nothing

Comment: Hey Dean, I come back again to tell you that your code work ! In fact **item.id** must be without quote ! `{% set photo_size = function('get_field','photo_size',item.id) %}` I think you can edit your answer. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Yes of course sorry, otherwise you are passing "item.id" as as string instead of the actual ID :) Glad it worked out. I don't think it's the best way - ideally I like to offload this sort of stuff into the php file but I think its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dean for your answer. It work well with some corrections.

For those who want to know the right code is :

```
{% for item in post.meta('photos') %}
    {% set photo_size = function('get_field','photo_size',item.id) %}
    <img src="{{ item.url }}" class="gallery__img {{ photo_size }}" alt="{{ item.alt }}">
{% endfor %}>
```